# Specify width and height of an image in php

Tags: php, html, css, image

I created a variable in PHP where I store HTML code:

```
$success = (
"<p>Result:</p><br>
<table style='margin-bottom:0; color:#000;'>
    <tr>
        <td>Option1:</td>
        <td>
        <img src='block.gif'
        width= ".(100*round($option1/($option1+$option2+$option3),2)).
        "height='20px'>".
        (100*round($option1/($option1+$option2+$option3),2))." %" ."
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Option2:</td>
        <td>
        <img src='block.gif'
        width= ".(100*round($option2/($option1+$option2+$option3),2)).
        "height='20px'>".
        (100*round($option2/($option1+$option2+$option3),2))." %" ."
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Option3:</td>
        <td>
        <img src='block.gif'
        width= ".(100*round($option3/($option1+$option2+$option3),2)).
        "height='20px'>".
        (100*round($option3/($option1+$option2+$option3),2))." %" ."
        </td>
    </tr>
```

This code is shown as a result of a poll and seems to be working so far. The width of 'block.gif' is equivalent to its according value. My problem is that for some reason the height is also rendered the same way, although I set its value to 20px.

I assume the error lies somewhere in the syntax but I just can't find it.

Comment: Hmm... try without the `%` unit. let the number be in `px` or unitless.

Comment: check the html, your missing units and quotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your code,

```
width= ".(100*round($option1/($option1+$option2+$option3),2)).
    "height='20px'>".
```

if the value of that big expression is `10`, it'll create,

```
width= 10height='20px'>
```

This is the problem. Correct form is,

```
width='10px' height='20px'>
```

So you need to change the code accordingly. Just move the space  and add two single quotes.

```
width='".(100*round($option1/($option1+$option2+$option3),2)).
    "px' height='20px'>".
```

Comment: That was it, awesome! Thank you so much for you help, you made my day :)